# How does cadence handle fault in various failure condition?

Tags: cadence-workflow

Cadence is a fault tolerant stateful code platform. How does cadence handle fault in various failure condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are al kinds of failures in distributed systems and Cadence provides various options to them.

Here is the list from myself. It may not be complete. But I will try add more if I can think of.

#### activity

- Activity failure and retry. See https://cadenceworkflow.io/docs/concepts/activities/#timeouts
- Also note that long running activity can recover from checkpoints via “heartbeat “

#### workflow

- By design of event sourcing models, a workflow can recover from any point left when a worker crashed. See https://cadenceworkflow.io/docs/concepts/workflows/#state-recovery-and-determinism
- Workflow can also have retry policy like activity to retry on failure automatically https://cadenceworkflow.io/docs/concepts/workflows/#workflow-retries
- On certain scenarios the failure is caused by bad code change which leads to wrong states. Cadence provides “reset” tool to reset workflow to any point of time.
  See https://cadenceworkflow.io/docs/cli/#reset-and-restart
- On top of reset, Cadence also allows you to reset by deployment. This is useful to reset a big number of workflow(eg millions of).

#### Cadence server cluster

Both activity and workflow workers are stateless.

Cadence server is a highly available and scalable service provides the durability.

- The durability is from underlying design and persistence storage ( by either Cassandra, MySQL or Postgres)
- In a single cluster setup, Cadence service is running with different independent shards. The whole cluster consists of different hosts. Any failed host can be replaced by another.
- Cadence provides Cross data center replication to provide much higher availability https://cadenceworkflow.io/docs/concepts/cross-dc-replication/#global-domains-architecture